# Неправильное чтение с базы данных

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, pdo

Есть php код

```
<?php
class ajaxValidate {

    function formValidate() {
        //Put form elements into post variables (this is where you would sanitize your data)
        $categoryflag=$_POST['categoryflag'];
        $subcategoryflag = $_POST['subcategoryflag'];

        //Establish values that will be returned via ajax
        $return = array();
        $return['msg'] = '';
        $return['error'] = false;
        $return['querycontent']='';
        $return['header']='Моноблоки';
        $return['countrecords']=0;
        
        require_once('config.php');
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

        //Begin form validation functionality
        if (!isset($subcategoryflag) || empty($subcategoryflag)){
            $return['error'] = true;
            $return['msg'] .= '<li>Error: Field1 is empty.</li>';
        }
        
        //Begin form success functionality
        if ((!$return['error']) && $subcategoryflag=='Моноблоки'){
            $return['msg'] = '          <div><div class="FilterContainer"><div class="FilterSeoGroup FilterSeoGroup__seo" id="popularCollections"><h4 class="FilterSeoGroup__header">Популярные подборки</h4><div class="FilterSeoGroup__group_closed"><div class="FilterSeoGroup__item-wrapper"><a class="FilterSeoGroup__item" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki--nedorogie-monobloki/">Недорогие</a></div><div class="FilterSeoGroup__item-wrapper"><a class="FilterSeoGroup__item" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki--dlya-doma-m/">Для дома</a></div><div class="FilterSeoGroup__item-wrapper"><a class="FilterSeoGroup__item" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki--dlya-ofisa-m/">Для офиса</a></div><div class="FilterSeoGroup__item-wrapper"><a class="FilterSeoGroup__item" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki--win/">с Windows</a></div><div class="FilterSeoGroup__item-wrapper"><a class="FilterSeoGroup__item" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki--imac/">Apple iMac</a></div></div><div class="FilterSeoGroup__toggle-container"><button class="FilterSeoGroup__toggle-button buttonStyleDecorator buttonStyleDecorator_theme_ghostOrange buttonStyleDecorator_size_s Button" name="" type="submit" value="" tabindex="0" borderstyle="none"><span class="buttonStyleDecorator__text ">Показать все</span></button></div></div></div></div>'

        }
            $sql='SELECT * FROM monoblocks';
            $query=$pdo->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
            $return['outputtext']='<div style="width: 100%; border: 2px solid #e31235">';
                        
            while ($example=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                // $return['querycontent']='<div style="width: 100%; border: 2px solid red"></div>';
                // $return['outputtext'].='<div class="ProductCardBlock">';
                
                $sqloutput[$i][0]=$example[2];
                
                $i+=1;
                
                // $return['outputtext'].='</div>';
            };
            
            $return['outputtext'].='</div>';
            $sqlcountrecords = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM monoblocks';
            $querycountrecords=$pdo->prepare($sqlcountrecords);
            $querycountrecords->execute();
            $return['countrecords']=$querycountrecords->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['count'];
                    

        //Return json encoded results
        return json_encode([
                            'result' => $return,
                            'output' => $sqloutput
                            ]
        );
    }

}

$ajaxValidate = new ajaxValidate;
echo $ajaxValidate->formValidate();
?>
```

```js
        // такой же код, что и код выше - только для черных пунктов меню типа Моноблоки 
        let categoryflag='';
            $('.submenu__title a').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log('Inner check');             
                categoryflag=event.target.innerHTML;
                subcategoryflag=categoryflag;
                console.log(categoryflag);
                $.ajax ({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '../php/ajaxsubcategory1.php',
                    cache: false,                   
                    data: {categoryflag: categoryflag, subcategoryflag: subcategoryflag},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    complete: function(data) {
                        console.log(data.header);
                        console.log(data.countrecords);
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('check');
                        console.log(data);
                        $('.rightmenu').html(data.result.msg);
                        let centeroutput='<div id=\"topcenterarea\">'+'<h1>'+data.result.header+' '+data.result.countrecords+' товара' + data.output[0][0] + '</h1>'+'</div>';
                        /*$('.centerarea').html('<div id=\"topcenterarea\">'+'<h1>'+data.header+' '+data.countrecords+' товара'+'</h1>'+'</div>');*/ 
                        $('.centerarea').html(centeroutput);

                        //expandCollapsedFunction();
                }
            }
            );
        }
        );
```

В результате выдает следующую инфу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

несмотря на

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как добиться вывода 2-го столбца таблицы monoblocks (нумерация стобцов начинается с 0 для `id` - если я не ошибаюсь). Файл `config.php`

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myishop';
$user='root';
$password='';
?>
```

Comment: лучше не индекс используй, а имя колонки

Comment: видимо у тебя не существует data.output[0][0], так как в цикле while переменная $i не инициализирована при первой проходке, не имеет значения никакого